# Visibility converter based on another element width

Tags: xaml, visibility

I have a Silverlight application and I use MVVM.

I would like to display or hide a TextBlock, based on another element current width (or window width at least...). The problem is that I currently have 2 texts on each other if I reduce the width of my window so I need want to hide the second textblock in that case...

I'm a beginner and I know how to use a VisibilityConverter with a boolean from my ViewModel, but not like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind to a property of another element, you would do something like this:

```
Visibility="{Binding ActualWidth, 
             ElementName=TheThingWhoseWidthYouAreBindingTo, 
             Converter={StaticResource WidthToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

And then create yourself a `WidthToVisibilityConverter` that takes the width value and returns a Visibility value.

Comment: Thx, but the converter is only used when I run the application (width ActualWidth = 0.0). Is there a way to automatically use it each time I resize the window ?

Comment: How can I track the ActualWidth of a control from my ViewModel ?

Comment: Short answer, you don't want to track ActualWidth in the VM ... that is most definitely a display property and not something the VM wants to worry about. Maybe you want to abstract that out somehow though, or rethink your design. Why hide the second textbox when window is reduced? Why not, instead, wrap it onto a second line?

Comment: I have Listbox templates controls where the `width` of an inner item is bound to the `width` of a constraining grid, and that updates just fine whenever the layout changes. Try using width rather than `ActualWidth`